# MyBatis SqlSession autoCommit = false vs ExecutorType.BATCH

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I am currently working with MyBatis and I am wondering how these 2 guys are different.

```
openSession(false);
```

and

```
openSession(ExecutorType.BATCH,false);
```

It seems like that the results to the database are the same, but what about the performance? Are these 2 types of SqlSession different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first call uses the executor type which is configured in your `SqlSessionFactory`. If `BATCH` executor is configured then these two calls are absolutely identical and you will get the batch executor and the followup behaviour is identical.

In no executor type explicitly configured `SIMPLE` executor is used.

The difference between these two executor types can be seen in scenarios when several modifying statements are executed.

`SIMPLE` executor executes query immediately when the corresponding mapper method is invoked. `BATCH` executor uses `JBDC` batch API. That API does not send queries for execution immediately, but instead collects them and then does a single network call to the database. In some scenarios this may give performance gain.